# $-\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded below, right?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, compactness, natural-numbers

Parable:

I am asked to prove by contradiction that the set of negative integers $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded below. My professor writes
$$-\inf(-\mathbb{N})=\sup(\mathbb{N}),$$
and says that since $LHS\in\mathbb{R}$ and $RHS\not\in\mathbb{R}$, by the Archimedean Property, then by contradiction we have that the set of negative integers $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded below, as desired.

---

Question:

Could someone explain to me how this is so? I do not yet see how it is so.

Comment: Specifically, I am wondering how the Archimedean Property is used here in this explanation.

Comment: Please do not use questions to lash out at other users.

Comment: It's not so. But if you put a negative in front of the sup on the right hand side of your displayed equation, it is.

Comment: @SecureSpace One of our rules here at math.SE is "Be nice." You can check out the FAQ for more specific information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality $\sup (S)=-\inf (-S)$ holds for any set of reals $S$. It implies that if $l$ is a lower bound for $-\Bbb N$, then $-l$ is an upper bound for $\Bbb N$. But $\Bbb N$ has no upper bound, because by the Archimedean Property, for every $x\in \Bbb R$ there is an $n\in \Bbb N$ with $x\lt n$. Therefore $-\Bbb N$ cannot have a lower bound.